# explain javascript: value assignment fails

Tags: javascript

```
var sc = new stuCore();
function stuCore() {
    this.readyPages = [];
    this.once = true;
    var self = this;

    // gets called asynchronously
    this.doPrepPage = function (page){

            if(self.once == true){
                   // still gets executed every time, assignment fails
                   self.once = false;
                   doSomeStuffOnce();
            }
    };

   this.addReadyPage = function (pageid) {

            console.log("readypage called");
            this.readyPages.push(pageid);
            if (!$.inArray(pageid, self.readyPages) != -1) {
                    this.doPrepPage(pageid);
            }
    };


}
```

why does this assignment fail? I thought I knew the basics of js, but I'm stumped by this. And furthermore what would be a possible solution? call a constructor first and set the variable there?

**EDIT:** 
gets called like this in some other script:

```
  sc.addReadyPage(self.id);
```

Comment: *`// gets called asynchronously`* How exactly are you calling it? How are you calling `stuCore`? It **works fine** for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/KwRKf/

Comment: where are you checking the value of self.once? and is the function executed more than once?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? What is `this` at the moment you assign it to self?

Comment: Provide more context: the value of this depends on where you are calling this code from (and/or if you are using constructor syntax with the 'new' operator). If you call stuCore() from two different contexts, the doSomeStuffOnce() will be called twice...

Comment: Sorry, but the code you posted does not have the problem you describe... have a look at my demo. Or your description is not very accurate. You will be able to call `doPrepPage` at least once for *every instance* you create.  Either you provide one yourself, which shows the problem, or we cannot help you.

Comment: @tucuxi, could you elaborate more: what do you mean with two different contexts? I am using a constructor with the *new* syntax - there is no stuCore constructor function. @ Felix thanks for the jsfiddle example, I looked at the code again, though I couldnt find an instance or function that could otherwise possibly have an influence

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery.inArray` function will return the index in the containing array for the given value. Your script pushes `pageid` into `this.readyPages` before checking whether it exists in `self.readyPages`. `this.readyPages` and `self.readyPages` are the same array reference, so the result will always be zero or greater, so the condition that calls `doPrepPage` will never run.

You could try switching their order around:

```
this.addReadyPage = function (pageid) {
        console.log("readypage called");
        if ($.inArray(pageid, self.readyPages) != -1) {
                this.readyPages.push(pageid);
                this.doPrepPage(pageid);
        }
};
```

(edit: Removed the additional `!`, thanks @chumkiu)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're calling `this.doPrepPage` as `<insert variable name here>.doPrepPage`?

If this is the case then your `var self` passes through to the anonymous function and is stored there, so everytime you call `this.doPrepPage` it takes the local variable of `self`.

Try setting `self` to a global variable, this way it will permanently modify `self` so each time `this.doPrepPage` is called it uses the updated variable.